# Error after installing Git

Tags: macos, git

I have just downloaded Git for my OS X 10.7.5

When I type:

```
which git
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/git
```

But when I type:

```
git --version
```

I get:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I'm looking for advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Check this out: [What is the “Illegal Instruction: 4” error and why does “-mmacosx-version-min=10.x” fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14268887/1038828)

Comment: Thank you. Seems my OS doesn't like the newest version of Git. I suppose I will try to download an older version of Git.

Answer (score 0):

I  had this problem and was able to install a working version using Homebrew.

```
# first uninstall the broken version
# mount the DMG for the broken version using Finder
# "type" this with the tab key! it saves typing and fixes the version number
cd /Volumes/Git\ 2.0.1\ Snow\ Leopard\ Intel\ Universal/
./uninstall.sh
# make bash forget about the uninstalled binary
hash -r
cd

# now install the working version
# assumes you have Homebrew installed
brew install git
git version
```